# SPARQL: Date conversion

Tags: r, date, datetime, timezone, sparql

In the R package SPARQL, `xsd:date` datatypes are by default converted into Unix time. This is a problem because this involves two date transformations - the first taking place within the function SPARQL() - which are determined by the local system time zone. This is a problem if you say, let's say in Sydney, Australia (`Sys.timezone() == "Australia/Sydney"`) because the following query, requesting the date of the 2016 US presidential election

```
query <- "SELECT ?date WHERE {wd:Q699872 wdt:P585 ?date}"
res <- SPARQL('https://query.wikidata.org/sparql', query)
as.POSIXct(res$results$date, origin = '1970-01-01')
```

will return `"2016-11-07"` instead of `"2016-11-08"` (the correct date), which is instead returned if

```
Sys.setenv(TZ='GMT')
res <- SPARQL('https://query.wikidata.org/sparql', query)
as.Date(as.POSIXct(res$results$date, origin = '1970-01-01'))
```

Is there any way to ask SPARQL to return date datatypes as characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how the R SPARQL package determines it's a date, but assuming it looks at the assigned datatype, you can coerce to string by retrieving only the lexical value:

`SELECT (STR(?date) as ?dateString) ....`

Of course this only works if the Unix time conversion happens on the result processing side, not during query evalation. If the latter is the case: get a better SPARQL engine.